# Manipulate a div based on a value

Tags: c#, jquery, css, webforms

I have a circular bootstrap circular  progress bar I need to be able to set the value of the div in the code behind at the min it is set as follows

```
<div class="circle" style="padding-right: 0px;">
    <div class="c100 p25">
        <span>
           <dx:ASPxLabel ID="paymentsCount" CssClass="dxeBase_DevEx-larger" Font-Size="Larger" runat="server" Text=""></dx:ASPxLabel>
                  </span>
               <div class="slice">
            <div class="bar"></div>
          <div class="fill"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

How would I be able to manipulate the p25 amount which is a percentage of 100% in code behind c# I have a value in payments count which is the amount of payments a user has made.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
<div class="c100 p<%: ThePrecentage %>">
```

?
but what your are saying is that you can manage any value of class?
like p1,p2,... p100?

Comment: hi yes that is somethign I persume that thepercnetage is a get and setter property on the back page

Comment: You have to post-back the page in order to change the value. Is that an acceptable solution?